# Does Hibernate log the values that it assigns to placeholders in prepared SQL statements?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, logging, log4j

Does Hibernate log the values that it assigns to placeholders in prepared SQL statements?  How can configure Log4j so that it writes these values to my log files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does (see the Chapter [3.5 Logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging)). Activate logging of the following categories:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Comment: Except that you end up with a query with a bunch of ? marks, and a ton of lines below where the parameters are spit out. So good, but not perfect. I had to end up writing an aspect to capture the SQL so I could properly log it in executable form...

Comment: Thank you!  http://ahoehma.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/hibernate-sql-logging-with-values/ explains how to use JDBC Logger (http://jdbclogger.sourceforge.net/) to log SQL statements including values of bind parameters.

Comment: For some reason, this didn't help in a Boot app: `logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=DEBUG

logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE`. Placeholder values are still not logged, e.g. for insert statements